# Hyperledger Fabric - With historian registry present, do we need user defined transaction models?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

How are user defined transactions actually helpful when the fabric has historian registry and it can be queried too. And, can these historian transactions be tapped into from the js chaincode logic.js? For example, can I use the data from transaction of type "AddAsset" and process it for some other purpose?

Comment: defined transaction classes is a convenient way of modeling how interactions take place against resources, such as assets and participants that they affect. It makes it easier from a dev perspective, and types can be abstracted, inherited etc. The other main factor is the ability to use ACLs to marshal/protect their use (in an authorization context), such as who can perform certain actions. (contd..)

Comment: ... Obviously you can query Fabric as you wrote, eg. from a Node JS transaction processor function (logic.js ?)  in yr Smart Contract - via the Fabric API using `getNativeAPI().getHistoryForKey` ...eg. as shown here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#calling-hyperledger-fabric-apis-in-transaction-processor-functions  As for AddAsset - an example query is `SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset WHERE targetRegistry == 'resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AssetRegistry#org.acme.account.BankAccount'` - you can for example ......

Comment: ...run a query then take some action on the results returned - see example here  https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js#L42